# import bulk users (csv file) into a 2003 active directory server

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a list of users that is pretty long, so long it would take too much time to do it one by one.

I've created so far the entire page enlisted like this:

"Name,Surname,Job,Login,Password"

I've used powershell and tried to put "adduser" along with the path in active directory, but i can't seem to make it work, "adduser" works on 2008 server but i do not know any orther way than this. and I couldn't find orther way at all.

i would like to ask if there is orther way to create a huge group of users with a command from powershell for 2003 servers, or even orther program than powershell that could import csv files to the active directory .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell 2.0 / ADDS cmdlets are likely not installed on your Windows 2003 server. If you install them, you can use `New-ADUser` as you would on 2008+.

See the following for instructions: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2011/03/how-to-install-powershell-on-windows-server-2003-and-enable-remote-powershell-managementall-servers-should-have-this-done/

Comment: i searched about using Adduser and found a page explaining all about it as well as your page that you linked mee, i managed to add my group of users thank you!